# Incoherent imaging through two aberrations

Tags: optics, lenses

I am doing independent research  trying to isolate and solve for distortion of an incoherent target when it passes through a known distortion in the medium and then an unknown distortion in the lens using Fourier Optics. I have seen a lengthy explanation of how coherent and incoherent distortion differ and how a distortion in the lens may be treated as a phase screen coincidental to a perfect lens, but I am suddenly unsure about how to combine multiple distortions.

Consider the following system attempting to capture the image of a dog pushing three cats in a stroller.

[image]

When the light passes through the medium, it is distorted. Also, when it passes through the lens
it is distorted. I know that for coherent systems, if a phase screen introduces an aberration $h$ on image $g$ then the output at the image $y$ will be
$$ y = |g \circledast h|^2,$$
where $\circledast$ is a convolution, and for incoherent images the measurement will be
$$ y = |g|^2 \circledast |h|^2.$$
For two distinct aberrations, how do they combine? For coherent imaging this is easy. For image $g$ and aberrations from glass $f$ and lens $h$, coherent measurements are given by
$$ y = |g\circledast h \circledast f|^2.$$
For incoherent imaging, can I say the following?
$$ y \stackrel{?}{=} |g|^2\circledast |h \circledast f|^2$$
Or is it
$$ y \stackrel{?}{=} |g|^2\circledast |h|^2 \circledast |f|^2?$$

Answer (score 1):

You convolve the squared magnitudes:

$y  = |g|^2 * |f|^2 * |h|^2$

In the context of a completely incoherent imaging system, $y = |g|^2 * |h|^2$ means is you convolve the intensity of the image ($|g|^2$) with the square magnitude of the transfer function of the imaging system ($|h|^2$) to get the intensity of the output image ($y$). If you apply another imaging system afterwards, you can treat $y$ as the intensity of the input to your second imaging system and perform another convolution.

Comment: Is there a concise proof of this around? The derivation of $y=|g|^2||h|^2$ was long and involved introduction of a random phase term at the image then solving for the the expectation of the resulting quantities in the far field and focused using a perfect lens (Tyo, Linear Systems and Fourier Optics). I was going to try and reproduce the result with a dual term but the potential for chaos is high.